# How to fold an event stream into a table?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'm trying to experiment a pure-postgres event sourced projection, and I'd like to represent a stream of events as a table:

imagine this flow of events:

```
┌───────┬───────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ order |        type           │ topic │           payload            │
├───────┼───────────────────────┼───────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│ 1     | user-registered       │ users │ {"name": "john"}             │
│ 2     | user-changed-password │ users │ {"name": "john", "activation_token": "1234"} │
│ 3     | user-registered       │ users │ {"name": "bob"}              │
│ 4     | user-banned           │ users │ {"name": "bob"}              │
└───────┴───────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

I'd like to create a view of the current state of active users containing:

```
┌──────┬──────────────────┐
│ name │ activation_token │
├──────┼──────────────────┤
│ john │ 1234             │
└──────┴──────────────────┘
```

In this example, there is only 1 active user because the second user has been banned.

So my question is: how could I "fold" the `events` table to end up with the `active_users` table ?

I tried to use `case` expressions but it's so hard to merge records:

```
create view users as
    select case type
        when 'user-registered' then (payload->>'name', null, true)
        when 'user-changed-password' then (null, payload->>'activation_token', true)
        when 'user-banned' then (null, null, false)
    end from es.events where topic = 'users'
    order by "order" asc
;
```

Comment: Unclear. Imagine records 2 and 3 are swapped (or it is impossible?). Then you cannot determine what user have changes the password - John or Bob. And you cannot determine does John matches the provided conditions or not. PS. Moreover, I don't see any choice to understand what record occures before and what occures after...

Comment: Indeed, for simplicity's sake I omitted to include the full schema, but I can guarantee correct ordering using a column I didn't include here. My main point was more about folding than ordering though.

Comment: a simplistic example would be https://medium.com/@tobyhede/event-sourcing-with-postgresql-28c5e8f211a2#abc0 but I want to go the extra mile

Comment: for now I abandonned any hope to declaratively fold and went imperative https://gist.github.com/docteurklein/868dcd62c86d95e688130fea09f0e45a

Comment: seems it would be easier to maintain a materialised view using an on-insert trigger off the events table (assuming that history is inserted in-order and never reverted)

Comment: `distinct on` and `group by` are good for folding, we can't give you an example without a usable schema.

Comment: @Jasen and @Akina I added the `order` column to guarantee the order of interpretation of each event. If you have an example of `group by` and/or `distinct on` I would love to see it, even if it doesn't exactly match my use case. i'm curious to learn about it anyway :) thanks for the answers already!

Answer (score 1):

assuming the are no duplicate events you can do this.

```
create view "users" as
  select payload->>'name'
  from es.events
  group by 1
  having
      sum ( case type 
            when 'user-registered' then 1
            when 'user-banned' then -1 
            end ) > 0
union 
  select payload->>'activation_token'
  from es.events
  where type='user-changed-password';
```